# Mix jQuery UI elements with angularjs in jQuery dialog

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I'm attempting to autocomplete a dialog textbox using angularjs. To start with I'm just trying to get some databinding working :

http://jsfiddle.net/WzEvs/279/

The code :

```
<div ng-app="">
        <div id="dialog-form">

            <label for="name">Name</label> <input type="text"
                name="name" id="name" ng-model="data.message" /> 
                <h1>{{data.message}}</h1>

        </div>
    </div>

$( "#dialog-form" ).dialog({
      autoOpen: false,
      height: 250,
      width: 350,
      modal: true,
      buttons: {
            Ok: function() {
              $( this ).dialog( "close" );
            }
          }

    });


$( "#dialog-form" ).dialog( "open" );
```

But the binding is not working correctly. I'm angualrjs beginner , im not sure whats going wrong as it works if I do not use a dialog.

Update : If I remove the Dialog code it works as expected :

http://jsfiddle.net/WzEvs/280/

Comment: did u include the angular.js file...?

Comment: @Srinath yes, please see question update

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One should write jQuery DOM manipulations within Angular's framework, either in a directive, animation, or using angular.element().

Here's an example where I've converted code to a directive:

```
// HTML
<div ng-app="app" dialog-form=""></div>


// JS
angular.module("app", []);

angular.module("app")
    .directive("dialogForm", function () {


    return {
        restrict: "A",
        template: "<div id='dialog-form'><label for='name'>Name</label> <input type='text' name='name' id='name' ng-model='data.message'><h1>{{data.message}}</h1></div>",
        controller: function ($scope, $element) {
            $scope.data = {};
            $scope.data.message = "";
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            element.dialog({
                autoOpen: false,
                height: 250,
                width: 350,
                modal: true,
                buttons: {
                    Ok: function () {
                        element.dialog("close");
                    }
                }
            });

            element.dialog("open");
        }
    };
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/SirTophammHat/WzEvs/282/